# if input two input tag have same value then give alert - javascript only no jquery

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="newfile" >
    <ul>
        <li><input value="test1" type="radio" name="abc" onclick="getResults()" /></li>
        <li><input value="test2" type="radio" name ="abc" onclick="getResults()" /></li>
        <li><input value="test1" type="radio" name ="xyz" onclick="getResults()"/></li>
        <li><input value="test2" type="radio" name="xyz" onclick="getResults()"  /></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my html now i want if any two radio button having same value like ="test2" or "test1" give me alert

i tried to get value in loop

```
<script>
function getResults() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            alert(radios[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

but not getting how to compare the value of two checked button and get alert.

over i want if any two radio button having same value give me alert else nothing should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help?

```
function getResults() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var dupDetector = {};
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
         // value = radios[i].value; // add a prefix to avoid built-in property names
            value = 'I_' + radios[i].value;
            if (dupDetector[value]) { 
                alert(radios[i].value);
                return;
            }
            dupDetector[value] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for @meiamsome to warn me that if the `value` is built-in object properties, the predicate will be always true although there are no duplicates. To avoid it, add a dummy prefix to it.

Comment: What if value is "toString" or "hasOwnProperty" or one of the other JavaScript Object's built in properties? This will alert on non-duplicates.

Comment: @meiamsome Would any value of input tags be an object instead of a string?

Comment: @neuront The problem is not it being an object - the way you're storing the values uses an object `dupDetector`. As it is an object `dupDetector['toString']` is already defined, so if any of the radio boxes' value was `'toString'`, it would alert as a duplicate.

Comment: @meiamsome Sorry I see... Would it work if change the predicate to `dupDetector[value] === true`?

Comment: @neuront It would solve it for the majority of cases, however it could be that the property of the object is true and so checking this would still alert when there was no duplicate.

Comment: @meiamsome I've got a better plan in the latest revision :D

Comment: @neuront You're still missing the reason I would prefer arrays over objects here - what if the default object has a property `I_kkdkdk`? Admit-ably, it's unlikely, but the array method rules this out entirely.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getResults() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var values = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            var found = false; //Represents if we have a duplicate
            for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { //Loop through previous items
                if(values[j] == radios[i].value) { //Duplicate?
                    found = true; // Flag it
                    break; //Exit 'j' loop
                }
            }
            values[values.length] = radios[i].value; //Add value to previous items
            if(!found) continue; //If there was no duplicate, continue to next item
            alert(radios[i].value); //There was a duplicate, alert and return
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```